# Error while executing GET request (Unhandled: GET)

Tags: web, backend, ktor

I tried to execute GET request but I got this error.

[image]

Bug is obvious here, but I don't know what is a problem.

```
suspend fun getNotesForUser(email: String) = notes.find(Note::owners contains email).toList()
```

Here is route code

```
route("/getNotes") {
    authenticate {
        get {
            val email = call.principal<UserIdPrincipal>()!!.name
            val notes = getNotesForUser(email)
            call.respond(OK, notes)
        }
    }
}
```

Note class:

```
data class Note(
val title: String,
val content: String,
val date: Long,
val owners: List<String>,
val color: String,
@BsonId
val id: String = ObjectId().toString()
```

All of my POST request are working, but this one GET is not.

Answer (score 0):

The `authentication` plugin for ktor [docs](https://ktor.io/docs/authentication.html#basic-usage) give the example of laying out the router in a different way to how you specified. Sample code:

```
routing {
    authenticate("myauth1") {
        get("/authenticated/route1") {
...
```

However in your code you pass in the route like:

```
route("/getNotes") {
    authenticate {
        get {
...
```

Could you try that approach specifying the route in `get` rather than in `route`?